# Path to dynamic object?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a system_settings table which has a key and value columns. The key looks something like `general.site.something.config` and the value is a simple string.

I'd like to have a static class which, upon initialization, reads the settings and caches the values. Furthermore, I'd like to be able to access the settings in an OO way, such as `SystemSetting.CACHE.General.Site.Something.Config` in order to pull back the value for that key. Basically turning the rows in the table into a tree.

Is there an easy way to do this in Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: Possible? Yes. Easy? Depends on your viewpoint. Is this really the best design you can come up with?

Comment: Probably not. Was more curious if this was doable or not. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR, No. No easy (read 'built-in') way atleast.

The syntax you want is not the way things happen in Ruby (without over-plumbing, that is). To have a look at the over-plumbing I'm referring to, [have a look at the code I wrote for this example](https://gist.github.com/kgrz/8845603) that demonstrates some of the desired functionality you want. I wouldn't suggest using it though and that's the same reason I'm not posting it here.

Comment: Good example, and it makes sense. (I won't use it in production it's more of an exercise to understand how to create hierarchical classes on the fly). Thanks!